# Fab button android onClick is crashing the app?

Tags: java, android, material-design

The (Floating action button) works but when I try to set it as a button it crashes the app?

```
Button MyButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.fab);
MyButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
  public void onClick(View v) {
    // Perform action on click
  }
});
```

The above crashes the app, but when I remove it everything is fine? Any ideas?

https://github.com/makovkastar/FloatingActionButton

Comment: There is an official google implementation of FAB as part of the design support library: https://github.com/chrisbanes/cheesesquare

Comment: Agree, better to use the official one now that it's part of the support lib.

Comment: Oh really, interesting, I will check it out and see. Makes sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The FloatingActionButton from this library extends ImageView which extends View:

https://github.com/makovkastar/FloatingActionButton/blob/master/library/src/main/java/com/melnykov/fab/FloatingActionButton.java

It is not a subclass of the Android Button. Cast instead to FloatingActionButton:

```
FloatingActionButton myButton = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
```